# How to get sponge type material

Tags: materials, node-editor

Im trying to get a sponge type material. like this

[image]

Uptill now i have tried this.

[image]

But my result not near to it.

I know its lot missing anybody help me how to get that material.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image: final]

I would use a much simpler setup:

[image: nodes]

**Math > Round** to make texture black and white and **Math > Multiply** to control **Volume Density**.

You can use different textures to get different results, I've made examples above with **Noise**, **Voronoi** and **Wave**.

As always with **Volume Shaders** don't forget to crank up **Ligth Paths > Volume** to something more than 0.

[image: volume]

Comment: A little help i tried the notes but im not getting the effect as seen above in the answer. Can you plz go through my file and let me know plz [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4916" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4916/)

Comment: @atek Apply Scale and Rotation on your objects and lower down Noise Scale.

Comment: I have tried to lower the scale and apply rotation scale yet to did not get the effect u have shown in above screenshot.a solid sponge effect. http://pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=08fa927e937bd7c78aa006c5952da8b9

Comment: Thanks for the material this is the Final result : https://imgur.com/gallery/T6d9CEy

Comment: There's also a recent video for making a procedural sponge material from Ryan King [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VvD0ql9OvdE).