# Create Indian dish 'idli' texture and rough edges?

Tags: texturing, shaders

[image]
This is the image of the dish I am trying to make in Blender, I am having hard time with the texture and randomness of it as all the pores are not exactly circular.

I also needed help with the rough and irregular edges.

Comment: Mmm.. I love idli. Try searching on ['sponge'](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/110003/35559)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84745/create-irregularly-shaped-gaps-in-cube/84845

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple speaking, with basic sponge textures or wall pores textures we can make idli textures.

found a "sponge texture" from google images.
[image: 1]

then converted it to blackandwhite image using Photoshop
[image: 3]

and used that blackandwhite image to covert it to NormalMap image Filters>3D>NormalMap(or)BumpMap.
[image: 2]

Made a simple scene containing a plate and idli. Making chutney would take quite a time.. so just added a plate and idli. Then unwarped idli and added above textures and hence this final render fellow indian.
[image]

or for detailed texturing try what @Robin Betts said in comments section.